# Does $\left\lfloor\frac{x^2+x}{i}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{x^2}{i}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{x}{i}\right\rfloor$?

Tags: proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Does $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2+x}{i}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2}{i}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{i}\right\rfloor$?

where $i \le x^2$ and $x$ are any positive integer.

Intuitively, this doesn't seem correct to me but here's my argument which appears valid:

(1) There exists an integer $a$ such that:  $x \equiv a \pmod i$ where $0 \le a < i$

(2) $\left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2+x}{i}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2}{i}\right\rfloor = \dfrac{x^2 + x - a^2 - a}{i} - \dfrac{x^2 - a^2}{i} = \dfrac{x-a}{i} = \left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{i}\right\rfloor$

Is my argument wrong?  Is my intuition wrong?

Comment: $\left\lfloor \frac{4 + 2}{3} \right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{4}{3} \right\rfloor \neq \left\lfloor \frac{2}{3} \right\rfloor$

Comment: If $0 \leq a < i$ then you can't conclude that $0 \leq a^2 < i$.

Comment: Nice.  So the mistake is the subtraction by $a^2$.  Thanks.  I suspected it was wrong.

Comment: So, it is only true when $\left\lfloor\dfrac{a^2+a}{i}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\dfrac{a^2}{i}\right\rfloor$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider x = 7 and i = 5. 
you get

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{49+7}{5}\right\rfloor = 11$

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{49}{5}\right\rfloor = 9$

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{7}{5}\right\rfloor = 1$

as you see the equation doesn't hold.

Your intuition is right and the argument is wrong. The same argument should follow the following logic

$\dfrac{x}{i} = k + \dfrac{a}{i}$ where $k$ is highest possible positive integer without making term a negative

$\dfrac{x^2}{i} = l + \dfrac{a^2}{i}$

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2+x}{ i}\right\rfloor = k + l + \left\lfloor\dfrac{a+a^2}{i}\right\rfloor$

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{x^2}{i}\right\rfloor = l + \left\lfloor\dfrac{a^2}{i}\right\rfloor$

$\left\lfloor\dfrac{x}{i}\right\rfloor = k + \left\lfloor\dfrac{a}{i}\right\rfloor$

as you see the floor terms are not necessarily equal. There could be cases when $a+a^2$ 
is higher than $i$ when both $a$ and $a^2$ are less than $i$.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I hope it's ok that I converted your answer to latex.  I think that it makes it more readable.  Cheers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wanted to make it more readable but didn't have much time and didn't want to leave the question unanswered.